# Nitro Pro 10 -- Javascript no funciona correctamente al generar pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf

Bueno, la cuestion es que he creado un pdf con campos de manera que los datos de estos actualiza otros campos que no son editables. Bien, dentro del propio programa funciona sin problema alguno. Sin embargo, abrirlo con Adobe Acrobat o cualquier otra aplicacion es una odisea: no se muestran todos los campos, no se rellenan correctamente, algunos ponen una combinaciom realmente extraña de caracteres...
La cuestion es que solo funciona correctamente en Nitro Pro 10 cuando se supone que deberia funcionar en cualquier lector pdf (que reconozca Javascript, eso si).
Y lo curioso es que el errror varia entre lectores y entre dispositivos...
Que podria ser? Hay alguna forma de evitar esto?

Comment: Buen día @Slifer Dragon, deberías editar la pregunta y agregar que haces en tu código, para ver sí se encuentra algún error que pueda ser corregible